# Creating and Displaying multiple arrays simultaniously C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new to C# and programming as a whole and I've been unable to come up with a solution to what I want to do. I want to be able to create a way to display several arrays containing elements from three external text files with values on each line (e.g. @"Files\Column1.txt", @"Files\Column2.txt" @"Files\Column3.txt"). They then need to be displayed like this in the command line:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0telh1ils201wpy/Untitled.png?dl=0

I also need to be able to sort each column individually (e.g. column 3 from lowest to highest).

I've probably explained this horribly but I'm not sure how else to put it! Any possible solutions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Using DataGridView for view and System.IO.File.ReadLines("path") for reading files https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd383503(v=vs.100).aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Are they multidimentional or not? It makes a difference, at least in how I'm reading your problem

Comment: How is the data laid out in the files? Is there a delimeter of some kind? Is it one data item per line?

Comment: Each individual file has one data item per line with no delimeter, I need to display all three at once in a multidimensional array and then be able to sort individual columns within the new multidimensional array.

Comment: You mean store (in a multidimensional array), not display, right? Are all three files guaranteed to have the same number of items?

Comment: Yes, store in a multidimensional, and yes all three files have the same number of items.

Comment: Not sure I understand the multidimentional array. Can you clarify? What would the dimensions represent, and how many are you talking about? i.e. what would be the value of `Array[0, 0]`, compared to `Array [0, 1]`?

Comment: The array would contain three sets of data, a Day, Date and a Value, e.g.   Tuesday        24/03/2015        50.83

Comment: Ok, but what are the dimensions? And what is the relationship between Day and Date? Would 'Date' be an index, that contains many 'Days', and for each `Date\Day` combination there is a specific 'Value'?

Comment: Currently there is no relationship between Day, Date or Value other than the fact that in their native order they correspond to each other. In the text files the date is descending, both Day and Value correspond to it. I'm also not sure what you mean about the dimensions, (I'm so sorry, I'm terrible at this!)

Comment: Ok. I don't see the purpose of a multi-dimensional array, then, since normally there is some relationship between the dimensions. I can give an answer with a standard List<Tuple<>>...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be to store the corresponding items from each file in a `Tuple`, and then store those in a `List`. This way the items will all stay together, but you can sort your list on any of the `Tuple` fields. If you were doing anything more detailed with these items, I would suggest creating a simple class to store them, so the code would be more maintainable.

Something like:

```
public class Item
{
    public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The example below could easily be converted to use such a class, but for now it uses a `Tuple<string, string, string>`. As an intermediate step, you could easily convert the items as you create the `Tuple` to get more strongly-typed versions, for example, you could have `Tuple<DayOfWeek, DateTime, string>`.

Here's the sample code for reading your file items into a list, and how to sort on each item type:

```
public static void Main()
{
    // For testing sake, I created some dummy files
    var file1 = @"D:\Public\Temp\File1.txt";
    var file2 = @"D:\Public\Temp\File2.txt";
    var file3 = @"D:\Public\Temp\File3.txt";

    // Validation that files exist and have same number 
    // of items is intentionally left out for the example

    // Read the contents of each file into a separate variable
    var days = File.ReadAllLines(file1);
    var dates = File.ReadAllLines(file2);
    var values = File.ReadAllLines(file3);

    var itemCount = days.Length;

    // The list of items read from each file
    var fileItems = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();

    // Add a new item for each line in each file
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
    {
        fileItems.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(
            days[i], dates[i], values[i]));
    }

    // Display the items in console window
    fileItems.ForEach(item =>
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} = {2}",
            item.Item1, item.Item2, item.Item3));

    // Example for how to order the items:

    // By days
    fileItems = fileItems.OrderBy(item => item.Item1).ToList();

    // By dates
    fileItems = fileItems.OrderBy(item => item.Item2).ToList();

    // By values
    fileItems = fileItems.OrderBy(item => item.Item3).ToList();

    // Order by descending
    fileItems = fileItems.OrderByDescending(item => item.Item1).ToList();

    // Show the values based on the last ordering
    fileItems.ForEach(item =>
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} = {2}",
            item.Item1, item.Item2, item.Item3));
}
```